# How to implement interface with rest parameters?

Tags: typescript

I want to implement an interface which defines overload functions with rest params, the interface looks like this:

```
interface window {
    showInformationMessage(message: string, ...items: string[]): Thenable<string | undefined>;
    showInformationMessage(message: string, options: MessageOptions, ...items: string[]): Thenable<string | undefined>;
    showInformationMessage<T extends MessageItem>(message: string, ...items: T[]): Thenable<T | undefined>;
    showInformationMessage<T extends MessageItem>(message: string, options: MessageOptions, ...items: T[]): Thenable<T | undefined>;
}
```

I wrote the code like this:

```
function show(message: string, options: any, ...items: any[]): Thenable<undefined | string | MessageItem>
```

then it will tell me options and ...items is incompatible.

So could anyone give some help?

Comment: Please consider editing this code to constitute a [mcve], as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  The idea is to make it easy as possible for others to begin working on your issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that `show` is the function overload implementation, some notes on your code:

1. You cannot use `function` in an interface, just leave it out
2. Why declare separate overloads for `string` MessageItems? Just declare one generic type parameter for all possible types.
3. All your overloads return `Thenable<T | undefined>` (we assume, we left out the ones with string items). Then why does your function implementation declare `Thenable<string | MessageOptions | MessageItem>` as return type?

An example, how could you simplify your code and let compile it successfully:

```
// your overloads
function showInformationMessage<T extends MessageItem>(
  message: string,
  ...items: T[]
): Thenable<T | undefined>

function showInformationMessage<T extends MessageItem>(
  message: string,
  options: MessageOptions,
  ...items: T[]
): Thenable<T | undefined>

// your implementation
function showInformationMessage<T extends MessageItem>(
  message: string,
  options?: MessageOptions,
  ...items: T[]
): Thenable<T | undefined> {
  return ...
}
```

You could still wrap the function type in an interface, if you want. More infos on function overload in the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

Hope, that example goes in the right direction.
Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping first. I have removed the 'function' and change my implementation's return. It was my mistake. The interface is from vscode so it can't be changed, I just want to implement it but don't know how. The interface did has 4 overloads and 2 different return types. I will try to change the code like options?: MessageOptions first, and will give feedback tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to implement a function interface, what you normally do, is something like this: `const fnImpl: FnInterface = (arg1,...) => ...` . Args and return type should correspond to the least specific/common of the function overloads (the bottom one). Good luck!